# Why do I get an error why trying to use the ?. operator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game where I can destroy objects, including those that may be playing animations. I used the null-conditional operator (?.) to avoid errors, but I'm still encountering issues. In my code, I have a PlayAnimation method that uses the ?. operator to call the Play method on the anim object. However, I'm getting errors even with this approach. I'm using the 2022 version of Visual Studio

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Door : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject door;
    public Animator anim;

    public bool open = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        PlayAnimation(open ? "DoorOpen" : "DoorClose");
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        open = other.CompareTag("Player");
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        open = false;
    }

    private void PlayAnimation(string state)
    {
        anim?.Play(state);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I'm getting errors even with this approach" What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: When i delete the door it says that the Animator is destroyed but i am trying to access it

Comment: in general in this setup you should rather use two states, add transitions forth and back based on a [`Bool Parameter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html) as `condition` and set this one instead via [`anim.SetBool("nameOfBool", open)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetBool.html)

Answer (score 2):

The `?.` operator checks for truly null references, whereas Unity overrides the `==` operator for Unity objects to make references to destroyed objects be equal to null. So you cannot use this operator in these situations. Just replace it with:

```cs
if (anim != null) anim.Play(state);
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at OnTriggerStay method. maybe "other" is null !

Comment: The engine wouldn't be invoking that physics message if `other` was `null` .. the issue is rather in `anim?.Play(state);` where the `?.` operator works on `System.Object` level and bypasses the existence check of the `UnityEngine.Object` via the custom `==` operator